# Add Background music in html page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello friends I need to Add Background music in html page. I have tried 
this code.Its working in chrome but not in firefox. Is there anyway to use both browsers.

```
embed src="Music/music.mp3" autostart="true" loop="infinite"  width="400" height="20"
```

Comment: Tried?? What you have tried?

Comment: check http://www.thesitewizard.com/webdesign/backgroundmusic.shtml

Comment: check http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: I tried this also.<audio src="Music/music.mp3" controls>
</audio> Not working in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For all versions of Netscape, as well as Internet Explorer ("IE") 3.0 and above, you can use the following code:

```
<embed src="Music/music.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true"
width="2" height="0">
</embed>
```

For Opera and all IE versions, the following code works:

```
<bgsound src="Music/music.mp3" loop="infinite">
```